# iOS scene size changing?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a game built in SpriteKit, and I'm trying to resize it for iPhone X.

Here is my initial setup code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    authenticateLocalPlayer()
    var isiphonex = false
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436{
            isiphonex=true
        }
    }

    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    if(isiphonex){
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            print("ios11")

            skView.frame = CGRect(x: 39 , y: 0, width: 667, height: skView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height)

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }



    }

    let startScene = StartScene(size:skView.bounds.size)


    startScene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0892857, y: 0)
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    startScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

    skView.presentScene(startScene)
}
```

Then when the scene loads I do this:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    print(scene?.size.width)
    print(view.bounds.size.width)
    print(scene!.view!.bounds.size.width)
}
```

and they all print 667

But when I'm trying to change scenes during a touch and do this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print(scene!.size.width)
    print(scene!.view!.bounds.size.width)
```

}

they both print 812.

Why is this, and how can I get it to stay at 667?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting frame in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.
2. Check if any constraint is applied which is overriding the frame you are setting.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing the size of the ViewController's primary scene just results in it snapping back to the original size. To fix the problem I created a new SKView and added it as a subview to the ViewController's primary view. I then presented all my SKSCenes in that new SKView